# Can robots.txt be used to prevent bots from seeing lazily loaded content?

Tags: html, googlebot, css, robots.txt

Let's say that `googlebot` is scraping `https://example.com/page`.

- `example.com` has a `robots.txt` file that disallows `/endpoint-for-lazy-loaded-content`, but allows `/page`
- `/page` lazy loads content using `/endpoint-for-lazy-loaded-content` (via `fetch`)

Does googlebot see the lazy loaded content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googlebot will see the lazy loaded content after it has been loaded onto the correct page. The page will be taken as a whole once any lazy loaded content or dynamic content has been loaded as Google will evaluate the page as the end user would see it. All that having the exclusion in your robots.txt file will do is prevent Google from listing the endpoint for the lazy loaded content on its own.